# Network namespaces: Temporary failure in name resolution [Ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, python

This is my scenario:

I have two distinct network interfaces, each with their own static public and private I.P. (IPv4), attached to a single virtual network, which is attached to a single virtual machine. I'd like to be able to assign `eth1`, the secondary network interface, to its own network namespace, then use that namespace to execute a Python application that sends information to a MySQL database.

Essentially, I want to run two of these applications simultaneously on a single VM, but run them within separate namespaces so that my database receives queries from two different public I.P. addresses. Using namespaces was the best option I could find. I have the Python bit sorted (I'm using a Python wrapper for netns), but I'm struggling with what I believe to be the nameserver for the namespace.

I'm executing the following commands to create the namespace:

```bsh
>> sudo ip netns add 001
>> sudo ip link set eth1 netns 001
>> sudo ip netns exec 001 ip link set eth1 up
```

I then try to ping `google.com` and receive the following error:
`ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

I know I'm missing something, and I'll admit I'm a big noob when it comes to networking. Any help would be appreciated.

**FYI**: I'm using Azure cloud services for all of this. My DNS servers on both network interfaces are set to *Inherit from virtual network* and I.P. forwarding is disabled. The address space for the virtual network is `10.0.0.0/24` with the primary interface (`eth0`) using `10.0.0.4` and the secondary interface (`eth1`) using `10.0.0.5`.

**EDIT**: I think I'm getting the hang of understanding network routing, but I'm coming up with another error.

```bsh
>> sudo ip netns add 001
>> sudo ip link set eth1 netns 001
>> sudo ip netns exec 001 ip link set eth1 up
>> sudo ip netns exec 001 ip addr add 10.0.0.5/24 dev eth1
```

The default gateway for `eth0` is `10.0.0.1`, so I assumed I'd be setting `eth1`'s default gateway to the same address since they share the same virtual network.

```bsh
>> sudo ip netns exec 001 ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```